# Is it possible to implement the expiration mechanism into ethereum, or proof of stake for bitgesell coin?

Tags: proof-of-stake, cryptoeconomics

I am intrigued by the ideas of Silvio Gesell and found that there is a Bitgesell coin, which seems to be a bitcoin fork with proof of work. Basically I would like to know if there are other people out there who think that proof of stake is better because of less energy consumption and that the aging money mechanism propsed by Gesell could really be very good in economic terms. Should search on the ethereum website, or suggest it on the bitgesell github? Which implementation would be easier?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the "expiration mechanism"? If you have enough resources, experience and time it is doable to make changes to ethereum code. It will be much more complicated to submit them to the mainnet client.